# Swagger UI not showing controllers/routes for ASP.NET API

Tags: asp.net, swagger

I'm trying to setup Swagger for my API, I have the interface at http://localhost/myAPI/swagger, but my controllers/routes are not displayed.
I'm using .net-framework, not .net-core

Startup:

```
public class WebApiApplication : HttpApplication
{
    protected void Application_Start()
    {
        AreaRegistration.RegisterAllAreas();
        GlobalConfiguration.Configure(WebApiConfig.Register);
        FilterConfig.RegisterGlobalFilters(GlobalFilters.Filters);
        RouteConfig.RegisterRoutes(RouteTable.Routes);
    }
}
```

Route config :

```
public class RouteConfig
{
    public static void RegisterRoutes(RouteCollection routes)
    {
        routes.IgnoreRoute("{resource}.axd/{*pathInfo}");

        routes.MapRoute(
            name: "Default",
            url: "{controller}/{action}/{id}",
            defaults: new { id = UrlParameter.Optional }
        );
    }
}
```

Controller:

```
[RoutePrefix("v1/controller")]
public class TestController : ApiController
{
    [Route("client")]
    [HttpPut]
    public HttpResponseMessage CreateClient([FromUri] string id)
    {
        return new HttpResponseMessage(HttpStatusCode.OK);
    }

    [Route("portfolio")]
    [HttpPost]
    public IResponseItem<int> CreatePortfolio([FromUri] string id)
    {
        return new ResponseItem<int>
        {
            StatusCode = HttpStatusCode.Created,
            Message = "Portfolio successfully created",
            Item = 12
        };
    }
}
```

Swagger config :

```
public class SwaggerConfig
{
    public static void Register()
    {
        var thisAssembly = typeof(SwaggerConfig).Assembly;

        GlobalConfiguration.Configuration
            .EnableSwagger(c =>
                {
                    c.SingleApiVersion("v1", "WebAPI");
                })
            .EnableSwaggerUi(c =>
                {
                });
    }
}
```

I'm new to this so I'm probably missing something

Comment: Startup.cs, anything done here? Try this https://github.com/CodeMazeBlog/swagger-ui-asp-net-core/tree/master/SwaggerUI

Comment: @Bharat question edited

Comment: There is a blog that teaches you how to do it step by step. http://wmpratt.com/swagger-and-asp-net-web-api-part-1/
I believe you are running asp.net-framework and not asp.net-core

Comment: @MarkDibeh I used this doc but it's not working, my swagger is empty.
It detects my controller but the routes are not displayed...

Comment: @MarkDibeh exactly, I'm using asp.net-framework. Is it the issue ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

first of all, it seems you made a mistake in RoutePrefix section. If you mean by defining `v1/controller` to use the name of your controller dynamically in the path, you should put [] around it like this:

```
[RoutePrefix("v1/[Controller]")]
```

and about the registration. you need to remove {} from your code.your code should be like the following:

```
 GlobalConfiguration.Configuration
            .EnableSwagger(c =>c.SingleApiVersion("v1", "WebAPI"))
            .EnableSwaggerUi();
```

I recommend to register swagger directly into the `Application_Start()` section.
Your final code should be like this :

```
public class WebApiApplication : HttpApplication
{
    protected void Application_Start()
    {
        AreaRegistration.RegisterAllAreas();
        GlobalConfiguration.Configuration
          .EnableSwagger(c => c.SingleApiVersion("v1", "title of your api"))
          .EnableSwaggerUi();
        FilterConfig.RegisterGlobalFilters(GlobalFilters.Filters);
        RouteConfig.RegisterRoutes(RouteTable.Routes);
    }
}
```

and the address to refer is: `http://localhost:yourProgramPort/swagger/docs/v1`

I hope it is helpful.

Comment: The document is generated properly but there's nothing on the ui. I can manage with only the doc but for the consumers I need the ui

Comment: It seems I'm blind..... I didn't noticed that I could click on my controller name. The routes were collapsed ><